# possible drawback of UserID being of string type in ASP.NET Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

Have been developing an app which automatically handles auditing.

Many of my EF models inherit `FullAudited` class.

```
public class FullAudited<TPrimaryKey> : Entity<TPrimaryKey>, IFullAudited, ISoftDelete
{
    public DateTime CreationTime { get; set; }
    public string CreatorUserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ModificationTime { get; set; }
    public string ModifierUserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DeletionTime { get; set; }
    public string DeleterUserId { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

See, we have `CreatorUserId`, `ModifierUserId`, `DeleterUserId`.

Imagine a situation the app is running for years and we have myriads of records in the database - each of these fields contains GUID string like `5a7618ee-d279-4df9-9fe0-23f7df3053bd`.

We could easily switch from `String` to `long` of course, but I guess there's a good reason why Microsoft designed it to be `String`.

So if we leave `UserID` as `String` - **such an app will certainly require significantly more storage**.

Looks like the default type doesn't cover our needs, right?

Comment: You can calculate that: NumberOfUsers * DifferenceInSize

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about Microsoft's reason and I've not seen a formal reasoning behind this choice, but we can make educated guesses.

When you design a library like identity, you want the simplest and most common use-cases to be as easy to setup as possible.
One common use case is to migrate an existing user-base to identity. Your existing users might have `int`, `long`, `guid` or `string` as their primary key. So the most robust default is to choose `string` for primary keys to support everything.

Now this default is not good for some users, I rephrase your example:

If we have a table of user activities where the `string` foreign key to users table is dominant in row size, then we might have considered choosing a smaller primary key for the users table.

I'll consider that a less common (and more advanced) scenario than people wanting to migrate to Identity, and I agree with those who made that decision.

That said, I personally change to `int` or `guid` PKs depending on the project, as this will also reduce the size of all indexes containing `UserId`